# Ubuntu Crash on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

I'm on a Lenovo Y50 laptop using a virtual machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox). I've set it to 128 MB of graphics memory, and 1024 MB of Base Memory. I've also enabled 3D Acceleration. I start Ubuntu up and the screen Ubuntu 16.04 loads up fine.. Then the top bar sometimes appears, and I can see the setting wheel and time start to load..

Then this happens:
[image]

I'm not sure how to fix that. Thanks for all and any help. Sorry if I tag the wrong people, I'm new to the whole Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Did you verify the checksum for the ISO?

Comment: so this fixed it guys, it shows up now. and it's a 32 bit operating system, for some reason it only allows me to use 32 bit. and here's the fix Press RightCtrl+F1, then RightCtrl+F7. This will reset the graphics adapter (first into text mode, then into graphical mode again).

Comment: @John If you found a solution to the problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. This will reset the graphics adapter (first into text mode (TTY1), then into graphical mode again (TTY7)). I had to do this twice, one time it was just a blank screen with an underscore at the top right, when I hit <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> again, everything showed up like it was supposed to. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I assume you have to do this every time you boot, right? Also, when you say you had to hit RCF7 twice, you mean you hit it twice, or repeated the whole procedure (tty7->tty1->tty7) again?

Comment: So I think, you need to go to text mode to log on. Once you are logged on, you go back to graphics mode which is the RCtrl+F7 command. Then everything is fine. I've had to do this for both my laptop and desktop installations of virtualbox.